# Kivy Python - getting "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unzip'"

Tags: python, android, kivy, filenotfounderror

I tried to create an APK file by using WSL and get this:

```
# Unpacking Android NDK
# Run ['unzip', '-q', '/home/tarpetos/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b-linux.zip']
# Cwd /home/tarpetos/.buildozer/android/platform
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==1.4.1.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1024, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 93, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 172, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 701, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 497, in _install_android_ndk
    self.buildozer.file_extract(archive,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 616, in file_extract
    self.cmd(["unzip", "-q", join(cwd, archive)], cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.4.1.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 289, in cmd
    process = Popen(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'unzip'
```

I have a ***main.py*** file and a ***connection_voice.ogg*** file in the same directory and at first I thought the problem was connecting the audio file. But now I understand that the problem is not in the audio file.

```
music = SoundLoader.load('connection_voice.ogg')
if music:
    music.play()
```

And I don't understand what an ***'unzip'*** file or directory is. Please give some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to solve this you need to enter to terminal `sudo apt-get install unzip`. And than this problem will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).